# Scrolling disabled after navigating back on safari 9.1.2

Tags: html, css, scroll, safari, navigation

First of all, my apologies that I don't have a [minimal, verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) test case. The issue that I'm having occurs on Safari, but I don't own any Apple products.

On [this website](https://www.eenkadovoor.nl/), there is a bug where the user can't scroll the page anymore **after navigating back**. You can follow the link, click on one of the buttons, go back (by swiping, clicking the button or using a shortcut) and then you won't be able to scroll the page anymore by using either the trackpad or mousewheel. I'm basically clueless as to what could be causing this.

The user that reported this is using Safari 9.1.2

Comment: Just to confirm: I can reproduce this problem on my rMBP 15" (Mid 2015, OS X 10.11.6) with Safari 9.1.2. I spent almost a hour looking, but can't find anything that causes this.

Comment: (Can't test since I don't have Safari 9.1.2.). Are the CSS body property changing in the inspector after navigating back?
You have `body {overflow-x: hidden;}` in stylesheet.css on (line 38). Does it help to remove this (or any other body properties)? It might be a bug that has been corrected in Safari 9.1.3. I Could not reproduce this in Safari 9.0.x either

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem from Safari 6 - 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short:

**I believe the answer is:**  Nothing is wrong with your website's code.

---

In fact, **I believe it is hardware related** and that is why many people can not reproduce this problem and it only affects some users.

I have tested the site on every OS from Lion/Safari 6 to El Capitan/ Safari 9, with a trackpad and magic mouse, using my Macs and Browserstack.

In every scenario, the site was functioning normally.

As you have stated, **track pads are affected** and I would like to add that any **2 finger swiping** may be the exact reason and 1 finger swiping is not.

**And The reason I say it is hardware related:**  because users on Apple ran forums are complaining about this same problem and have said a **PRAM reset is what corrected the problem**.

[Swipes and scrolling stop working in Safari](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5467320?tstart=0)

**More users on Apple forums voice their complaints.**

[Apple users place the blame on everything from OS upgrades to system bugs and failing hardware .](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5511186?start=0&tstart=0)

---

**In the End:** One thing is certain. I have not seen one user claiming that it's a result of a website's coding.

Comment: My pleasure! We have both gained knowledge from your question -- Cheers

Answer (score 1):

i cannot test it 'cause i havn't any OSX but i've never had this problem when developing any website. Try to do not rely in overflow specifications on body, let it auto.
If something overflows the page in X-line then you've something bad-structured or bad-styled (if talking about responsive web development).
If something overflows in Y-line then it will be scrollable anyway even if you don't declare it on body's styles.

Then you declared box-sizing: border-box; AND position: relative; to all elements (*, *:after, *:before). Delete it too, no need to re-declare those properties and may cause issues when dealing with different elements.
Think that html elements have default properties, the good habit is to learn and understand it, not to change it as you want crazily...

Finaly, if you inspect the console you'll find some jquery errors that may cause lock some css classes or issues on page load.

```
1- Delete body's overflow declarations.  

2- Delete * stylings (* styles must be used only to homogenize text, as font  family and font width, or other few generic non-structure modificable things)

3- repair JQuery errors.
```

Hope it helps, Cheers!

Comment: i keep misunderstanding why you need overflow hidden. As overflow's documentation says (The overflow is clipped, and the rest of the content will be invisible) And the experience says that it may causes the content to be unscrollable. Overflow auto brings scrollbars if needed and overflow scroll's make the scrollbars appear, sometimes even if no need.

Its ok if you're using this for long time, but it's wrong. Anyway it could be fine if you start using bootstrap instead of doing it by yourself.

Try to do the points 1 and 2 and let's see what happen.

Comment: So if you don't wanna try some possible repair jobs to your website, why are you asking here? Exactly as you said, you're changing global structure defaults crazily and the way you do it makes me think you're not an expert on front-end development. If you understand the way elements are rendered and why them have those default properties there's no reason to override as you did. As you said is like you want to write a nobel with notepad, but trying to force different font stylings and colours on it. When you definetely want to look at this, comment body and * stylings and reply to this answer.

Comment: oh and... to modify opacity don't change z-index. And yes, it's a language (isnt really a programming language) which you can't do certain things. That's the reason for use js instead css to perform some specific jobs. I'm talking from my 8 years experience on front-end development and full stack development. At least you can add this at the bottom of your last-loaded CSS: @media(max-width:991px;){body{overflow:visible;}} Then, if something makes your website to not be responsive and you get scroll in x-line, you've errors in your structure. It's called debugging or testing,TEST, dont be lazy!

Comment: using jquery you can reach faster loads and simplest and clear scripts.
if it was well developed, with no horizontal scroll caused by errors or bad structure usage, google will never detect as wrong. Using js to reach jobs that can be done with HTML and CSS is deprecated due to load times and data charge amount on client device. As your website stats are not too god (62 requests, more than 3MB loading, 410ms to start loading, 1,57s to start rendering and more than 6,3s to full load) is this mobile friendly? i think you must change your methods instead of trying to fool google bots man

Comment: i really don't want to keep arguing for years. You asked something, i anwered with possible repairs and you are discussing those changes without testing. I'm wasting my time with your problems so if you don't wanna hear my advices and don't take much care to the repairs i suggest you then mark this post as completed with no solution and mark it as "due to the stubbornness of the man who ask". Cheers!